# Videos Stored in D7-s private file system do not play on Android devices

Tags: files

I have .mp4 video files that I store on my D7 site's Private File system. I am using Video JS module for videos.
I am having issues on playing them on devices (Phone, Tablet) running Android OS. 
Does anyone have a solution for this?

I had the same issue on iOS platform, the fix was using Resumable Downloads module for iOS.
For Android the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work on android device you need to pass .webm format along with .mp4 of the same video. Please check sample shown below:

```
<video id="my_vid_id" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="poster.png" data-setup='{}'>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
   <source src="movie.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

Comment: I use both .mp4 and .webm formats. My issue is related to videos being streamed from public/private file system. I can play the same video on Android Chrome browser stored on Drupal 7's public file system but i can't play the one that is stored on Drupal 7-s private file system. This seems to be a known issue. I wonder if anyone has a solution to point me to.

Comment: FYI the issue was dependent to Android OS and Mobile Browser. On Latest Android versions KitKat + and using Chrome or Firefox everything should work fine. I am assuming that the code in the video tags has no issues.